# how to remove animation from the MPMoviePlayerController when done is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want  to remove the transition animation that occur in  MPMoviePLayerController when the user presses done button . I used to  stop it  when the movie finishes on its own using the moviePlayBackDidFinish: notification but  its doesn't work, as in, the animation occurs. this code i used.

```
NSURL *fileURL=[NSURL URLWithString:mediaurl1];

moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 270)];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(donefinished:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];

[mediaView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
[moviePlayerController setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
```

this is my notification method to close the animation effect.

```
-(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification{



    [mediaView removeFromSuperview ];
    [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
   // [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];


}
-(void)donefinished:(NSNotification*)aNotification{


    [mediaView removeFromSuperview ];
    [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
    // [moviePlayerController setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use it.
-(void)donefinished:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [moviePlayerController stop];
    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    moviePlayerController = nil;
}
```

Comment: more than one hour i struggle to find the mistake . you have saved my time, i am not able to upvote , less reputation .@Monikanta